# How to play a sound when a certain number is generated?

Tags: javascript

I have found this: http://jsfiddle.net/FQSAH/1/
It runs every 2 seconds and generates a random number between 1 and 253. 
I'm not a programmer but I found my way to modify these values for my specific situation. (Generate number between 1 and 9000 every 1 second, here it is https://jsfiddle.net/zL6wcfjo/ )
But now I need it to play a sound if it lands on a specific number. Let's say that number is 9000. Edit: It doesn't have to run all the time. It can be: Generate random numbers until a certain number is generated. When that number is generated, generating stops and a sound plays.

I found some topics here that resemble my problem but I'm can't manage on my own. I don't know anything about coding and don't even know to import a sound.

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

var ms = 1000;
var func = function () {
var randNum = getRandomInt(1, 9000);    // Gets random number between 1 and 9000
document.getElementById("element_id").innerHTML = randNum;
};

func();
setInterval(func, ms);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you must add the sound clip into the same folder as the code for the website.

Then you must reference that sound clip in javascript 
`var alert =  new Audio("alert.wav");`

replace .wav with the file format of the sound clip.

Then you can add an if statement at the bottom of the function like so:

```
var alert =  new Audio("alert.wav");
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

var ms = 1000;
var func = function () {
var randNum = getRandomInt(1, 9000);    // Gets random number between 1 and 9000
document.getElementById("element_id").innerHTML = randNum;
if (randNum == 9000){
  alert.play();
}

};
```

Comment: `new audio("alert.wav");` : Uncaught ReferenceError: audio is not defined. It must be `new Audio`, with uppercase A.